# converting database formats (mysql, ms access, ms excel, IBM DB2)

Tags: portability, database

We need to a good tool that we can run from a script to
automatically convert a (mysql, ms access or DB2) database 
to a (mysql, ms access, ms excel or DB2) database, 
while preserving the data types as much as possible (text, int, decimal, time...).

Do you know of such a tool?

---

I am looking for a solution, such as IBM Data Movement Tool. this tool converts from any database to IBM DB2, automatically. it maps the data types, creates the tables, and import the data automatically. and you can run it from the command line. the only problem is that the target database can only be a db2 database. I am looking for the same type of tool, from any database to any database. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0906datamovement/

Comment: Question is not very well stated. First of all, what do you intend with "Excel" in this case? It's not a DB - per se. Second, do you mean you start from a populated Access DB and get an equivalent, fully populated DB2 DB? Without exporting/importing data? All with a command line utility?

Answer (score 0):

Best I can provide for you is [SwissSQL products](http://www.swissql.com/products/index.html). I have used their trial stuff to help me convert schemas from MS SQL to Postgres, and they were quite useful.

*In theory* they can also convert full schemas, data, and even stored procedures. In practice you should read what their tools cover, because if you expect 100% conversion without any human intervention you will probably be disappointed.

Similar products may exist, (have you already googled for "convert DB2 to mySQL"?) but they will probably not cover exactly the mix you are interested in (for example, there may be tools specializing in converting from a range of DBs to mySQL, or from a range to MSAccess, but having a general purpose tool doing what you want for all the combination is probably too much to ask).

And I am pretty sure that in every case, you will have to verify the results and be ready to manually correct anything missing, truncated, or misinterpreted.

Comment: I asked the people from SwissSQL but they do not support ms access, and they do not plan to neither.

I am looking for a solution, such as IBM Data Movement Tool. this tool converts from any database to IBM DB2, automatically. it maps the data types, creates the tables, and import the data automatically. the only problem is that the target database can only be a db2 database. I am looking for the same type of tool, from any database to any database. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0906datamovement/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's the single silver-bullet for this problem. The best thing to look for is specific tools to help you along. Some things can already be done without additional tools, e.g. exporting Excel to CSV and importing CSV with MySQL's tools. Likely you'll just need to find the best tool for each specific case (with perhaps a few combined) and selectively use each depending on your desired input/output formats.

Comment: Exporting to CSV and importing from CSV, makes you loose the data type information (what it a int, decimal, varchar, blob...).

I am looking for a solution, such as IBM Data Movement Tool. this tool converts from any database to IBM DB2, automatically. it maps the data types, creates the tables, and import the data automatically. the only problem is that the target database can only be a db2 database. I am looking for the same type of tool, from any database to any database. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0906datamovement/